# Kubernetes logging architecture - NFS Persistent volume?

Tags: logging, kubernetes

In kubernetes cluster for microservice application to diagnose the issue we need logs.

1. Is is good idea to use NFS persistent volume for all microservice logs?
2. If yes, Is it possible to apply log rotation policy on NFS persistent volume based on size or days?
3. If we use ELK stack with filebeat it will need more resources and learning for customer to get the required log.

What will be best approach i.e NFS or ELK stack or mixed?

Answer (score 2):

1. NFS is ok as long as it is able to offer required performance.
2. You should apply lifecycle policy at Elasticsearch indices level. Modern Kibana has a nice interface for creation of lifecycle policies and overall monitoring of ES.
3. Never worked with Filebeat. We use EFK stack - Elasticsearch, Fluentd and Kibana. It works pretty well and is installed only using Helm Charts.